# How to get add, edit, next & previous buttons on HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an entry form to post data into a MySQL database (with a submit button) and it works fine. Now I want to have edit, next & previous buttons on it, to get next and previous record and also to edit them if needed.

I have searched on the internet but could not find a solution according to my requirement.

Comment: Next & previous button for what? For edit you want to create a PHP file and call it through ajax so whenever person clicks on edit record his ID along with changes will be sent to that PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should ensure that you have a column for the record ID that's an `INTEGER`, a `PRIMARY KEY`, and set to `AUTOINCREMENT`, let's call this `recordID`.

Let's take an example person table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    recordID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    firstName VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
    middleNames VARCHAR(250),
    lastName VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL
);
```

To query the first record, we can do:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE recordID = 1;
```

Now to edit the record, we can do:

```
UPDATE people SET firstName="NewName" WHERE recordID = 1;
```

Next we build an HTML form to display/edit this data in.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="recordID" id="recordID" />
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
    <input type="text" name="middleNames" id="middleNames" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" />
    <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Last of all you create some next and previous buttons to traverse through the records and populate the input fields, and then an edit button that sends the data to the server for it to update the database.

If you're feeling extravagant, you could use SQL's `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO people (firstName, lastName, middleNames, dateOfBirth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstName="?", lastName="?", middleNames="?", dateOfBirth="?";
```

In order to do an "in-place edit", you could add a variable to the querystring.
For example, if you want to edit recordID = 3, you could have the URL as: http://yourserver.com/person/?id=3&edit.

On the serverside you can check for edit by using `isset($_GET['edit'])`. If that returns true, than run your edit code and populate the fields/enable the edit functionality.

Comment: Dear Mr. Huw, I have a table with ID integer as primary key and autoincrement. My html form is inserting values in it with a submit button. I placed another button "previous" calling another php file but do not know how another php file will populate values in the same form.

Comment: Either copy and paste the form, or use a `$_GET` variable such as `?edit` and check to see if you're editing.
I've updated my answer, so let me know if that helps.